# Open set in product topology which is not "cylindrical"

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, product-space

I know that the product topology on $\prod_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{R}$ has a basis of the form:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^N U_i \times \prod_{i=N+1}^\infty \mathbb{R} \tag{*} $$

where $U_i\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm trying to give an example of an open set not of that form, and just wanted to verify the following example:

Let $U_N\in \prod_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$ U_N:= \prod_{i=1}^N (N,N+1) \times \prod_{i=N+1}^\infty \mathbb{R} \quad. $$

Given $\overline{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)$, if $\overline{a}\in U_i$ then $a_1\in(i,i+1)$, and if $\overline{a}\in U_{i+1}$ then $a_1\in(i+1,i+2)$. Hence $U_i\cap U_{i+1}=\emptyset.$

I think that $U=\underset{N=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup} }U_N $ is not of the form (*), but is open.

Since I have a tendency to get confused I was hoping if someone could verify this is indeed the case, and perhaps point me to a more exotic example which I can't see right now.

Comment: May be I am confused but isn't $U_{N+1}\subset U_N$ and thus $\cup_{N=1}^{\infty}U_N=U_1$?

Comment: I think they are disjoint, but I will try to add in an edit why I think this is the case.

Comment: If $i<x_i<i+1$ for $i=1,2,\dots, N+1$ then surely $i<x_i<i+1$ for $i=1,2,\dots, N$ so @PeterMelech is correct. Try it with $U_N=(0,N)^N$.

Comment: Okay, I wrote something else than what I had in mind. I will correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is fine, although you are trying too hard.

You can start with the following question: "what open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not of the form $I_1\times I_2$ for some open subsets $I_1,I_2\subseteq\mathbb{R}$?" And then simply generalize it to $\prod\mathbb{R}$. Like for example two overlapping squares forming a non-square:

$$U_1=(0,2)\times (0,2)\times \prod \mathbb{R}$$
$$U_2=(1,3)\times (1,3)\times \prod \mathbb{R}$$
$$U=U_1\cup U_2$$

Comment: That is an example of what OP says they want (an open set that isn't equal to a basis element) but the question title asks for something a little different: a non-cylindrical open set. Your example isn't a basic open set, but it is cylindrical.

Comment: @MJD I see why Freakish's example works, but I fail to see how is it cylindrical. Can you explain?

Comment: I don't mean anything subtle by it. I would have said that $S\times \Bbb R^\infty$ was a cylinder for every set $S$. But if you have a different idea of what “cylindrical” means that's okay with me.